# Non connection with database?

Tags: java, database, android-studio, authentication, android-room

I am newbie to Android Studio and i am creating a project with login and registration. I am using room technology and yet have searched on the Internet i couldn't find why i can't access my database. Although i call my database and it has data, from the background, in it, when i try to read it I find it empty. Please Help i don't knopw what to do!! Thank you!!

MY DAO FILE

```java
package com.example.myapplicationversion2;

import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Dao;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Delete;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Insert;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Query;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Update;

import com.example.myapplicationversion2.User;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface DAO {

    @Insert
    void insert(User user);

    @Update
    void update(User user);

    @Delete
    void delete(User user);

    @Query( "SELECT * from user where username=:username and password=:password" )
    User checkUser(String username,String password);

    @Query( "SELECT * FROM user order by user_id asc" )
    LiveData<List<User>> getAllUsers();
    @Query( "SELECT * FROM user order by user_id asc" )
    List<User> getUserNotLive();

}
```

MY DATABASE.class

```java
package com.example.myapplicationversion2;

import android.arch.persistence.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

@android.arch.persistence.room.Database( entities = {User.class,Questions.class,Users_Questions.class}, version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {
    private static Database instance;

    public abstract DAO userDAO();

    public abstract QuestionsDAO questionsDAO();
    public abstract Users_questionsDAO users_questionsDAO();


    public static synchronized Database getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance==null){
            instance= Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),Database.class,"database.db")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback( roomCallBack )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallBack=new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate( db );
            new PopulateDBAsyncTask( instance ).execute(  );
        }
    };

    private static class PopulateDBAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        private DAO DAO;
        private QuestionsDAO qDAO;

        private PopulateDBAsyncTask(Database db){
            DAO =db.userDAO();
            qDAO =db.questionsDAO();

        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            DAO.insert( new User("Vangelis","vakiskor@yahoo.gr","vakiskor","1234","Admin") );
            DAO.insert( new User("John","john@yahoo.gr","john","1234","User") );
            DAO.insert( new User("Administrator","admin@yahoo.gr","admin","admin","Admin") );
            qDAO.insert( new Questions( "Πως αξιολογείτε την μεταδοτικότητα του Καθηγητή;" ) );
            qDAO.insert( new Questions( "Πόσο ενδιαφέρον βρίσκετε το συγκεκριμένο μάθημα;" ) );
            qDAO.insert( new Questions( "Πως αξιολογείτε το γνωστικό επίπεδο των υπολοίπων συμφοιτητών σας;" ) );
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My LOGIN.class

```java
package com.example.myapplicationversion2;


import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.arch.persistence.room.Room;
import android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String EXTRA_USERNAME="com.example.myapplicationversion2.EXTRA_USERNAME";
    public static final String EXTRA_PASSWORD="com.example.myapplicationversion2.EXTRA_PASSWORD";

    private static int user_id;
    private EditText editTextUsername,editTextPassword;

    private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;


    private AppCompatButton appCompatButtonLogin;

    private AppCompatTextView textViewLinkRegister;
    private DAO checkUser;
    private DAO userDao;
    private Database database;

    User user;

    //private ViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_login );
        database=Database.getInstance( this );

        //database=Room.databaseBuilder( this, Database.getInstance( this),"database.db").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        database= Room.databaseBuilder( this,Database.class,"database.db" ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        nestedScrollView=findViewById( R.id.nestedScrollView );
        editTextUsername=findViewById( R.id.textInputEditTextUsername );
        editTextPassword=findViewById( R.id.textInputEditTextPassword );
        userDao=database.userDAO();

        appCompatButtonLogin = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.appCompatButtonLogin);

        textViewLinkRegister = (AppCompatTextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLinkRegister);

        appCompatButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(this );
        textViewLinkRegister.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.appCompatButtonLogin:
                user_id = v.getId();
                login();
                break;
            case R.id.textViewLinkRegister:
                Intent intentRegister=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegisterExistingUser.class);
                startActivity( intentRegister );
                break;
        }
    }

    private void login() {
        if ( !emptyValidation()){

            new Handler().postDelayed( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println( "====================================" );
                    List<User> list=userDao.getUserNotLive();

                    for (User tmp:list){
                        System.out.print( tmp.getUsername()+tmp.getPassword() );
                    }
                    System.out.println( "====================================" );

                    System.out.println ( "***" + editTextUsername.getText().toString() + editTextPassword.getText().toString() );

                    User user = userDao.checkUser( editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim(), editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim() );
                    if (user != null) {
                        if (user.getSpecialty().trim().equals( "Admin" ) || user.getSpecialty().equals( "admin" ) || user.getSpecialty().equals( "ADMIN" )) {
                            Intent accountIntent = new Intent( Login.this, AdminChoices.class );
                            startActivity( accountIntent );
                            emptyInputEditText();
                        } else {
                            Intent accountIntent = new Intent( Login.this, UsersQuestionsActivity.class );
                            startActivity( accountIntent );
                            emptyInputEditText();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText( Login.this, "Μη εγκεκριμένος χρήστης", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            },1000);
        }


        else{
            Snackbar.make( nestedScrollView,getString(R.string.error_valid_username_password ),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean emptyValidation() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty( editTextUsername.getText().toString() )||TextUtils.isEmpty( editTextPassword.getText().toString() )) {
            return true;
        } else{
            return false;
        }

    }


    private void emptyInputEditText() {
        editTextUsername.setText( null );
        editTextPassword.setText( null );
    }

    public static int getUser_id()
    {
        return user_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you, how do you try to read it? From what I understood in your post, it has data in the app, but when you try to open this i.e on the computer it's empty, right?

Comment: The data are added on the backgroung using Populate Async. And then i am use getInstance in the Login.class to get the data. After that i access the DAO file and use the data. Then it shows it is empty though it is not.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that you are trying to insert your data to the DB before it was fully created.
You should make sure the DB finished building before doing so.

I think what you can do is replace the AsyncTask with an EXECUTOR and also remove the `.allowMainThreadQueries()` call to make sure you are not running on the main thread.
I didn't test it but I think it should work.

```
public static synchronized Database getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance==null){
            instance= Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),Database.class,"database.db")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback( new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onCreate(db);
                        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                DAO dao =getInstance(context).userDAO();
                                QuestionsDAO qDAO = getInstance(context).questionsDAO();
                                DAO.insert( new User("Vangelis","vakiskor@yahoo.gr","vakiskor","1234","Admin") );
                                DAO.insert( new User("John","john@yahoo.gr","john","1234","User") );
                                DAO.insert( new User("Administrator","admin@yahoo.gr","admin","admin","Admin") );
                                qDAO.insert( new Questions( "Πως αξιολογείτε την μεταδοτικότητα του Καθηγητή;" ) );
                                qDAO.insert( new Questions( "Πόσο ενδιαφέρον βρίσκετε το συγκεκριμένο μάθημα;" ) );
                                qDAO.insert( new Questions( "Πως αξιολογείτε το γνωστικό επίπεδο των υπολοίπων συμφοιτητών σας;" ) );
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    })
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

Comment: Still the same!! It is like it is not seeing the database at all